# Error when trying to open a JDBC connection using Ballerina slbeta2

Tags: ballerina

I'm getting errors when I run a simple program that's trying to open a jdbc connection.

The sample code can be found at https://github.com/bondowe/dbtest.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

*OS: Windows 10
Ballerina version: slbeta2
Command: `bal run`*

*Error:*

```
SEVERE {b7a.log.crash} - ballerinax/java$0046jdbc/0_6_0-beta_2/$ConfigurationMapper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ballerinax/java$0046jdbc/0_6_0-beta_2/$ConfigurationMapper
        at bondowe.dbtest.0_1_0.$ConfigurationMapper.$configureInit(Unknown Source)
        at bondowe.dbtest.0_1_0.$_init.main(dbtest)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ballerinax.java$0046jdbc.0_6_0-beta_2.$ConfigurationMapper
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 2 more
```

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really Java is it? Looks like something *run by* Java…

Comment: @g00se - I agree the java tag is a bit misleading. The issue seems to be a configuration on the Ballerina side, not sure which one.
I'll remove the java & jdbc tags.

Comment: @Bondowe Can you try deleting `C:\Users\${username}\.ballerina\repositories\central.ballerina.io` directory and try again? This is a caching issue and will be fixed in a future release. Replace `${username}` with your windows username.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha - Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly after I deleted `central.ballerina.io` folder.

Comment: @Bondowe That's great. I added that as an answer for other users to resolve this issue in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a caching issue in ballerina and will be fixed in a future release. For now, users can remove:

- `/home/${username}/.ballerina/repositories/central.ballerina.io` directory on ubuntu
- `C:\Users\${username}\.ballerina\repositories\central.ballerina.io` directory on windows

and rebuild.